# SESSION in WordPress Plugin Development

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, session

I wondering  the session was disable in wordpress. I try to find some information on using session variables in the wordpress. I tried the following method to implement session variables in the wordpress site.

I tried this way.

```
<?php 
session_start();

$_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST['firstname'];

?>
```

If i echoing the `$_SESSION['firstname']` is not come's up. So I googled to find the reason why it doesn't support.

```
function register_session() {
    if (!session_id())
        session_start();
}

add_action('init', 'register_session');
```

This above method i tried and implemented but it also doesn't work.

Right now i integrating session in plugin so i don't want to edit the core file. Because i doing the custom plugin development.

How to enable the session in wordpress plugin. Any Suggestion would be great

Thanks.

Comment: There're 300+ search [results on this site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=session). Already read through them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't seem to be wrong, it's just how I would do it - see my [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/117260/22534) here. So the question would be is your session getting started? Try debugging this:

```
// do you have a session id
$s_id = session_id();
print_r($s_id);

// can you declare a bogus session variable, yours might just be empty
$_SESSION['bogus'] = 'bogus';
print_r($_SESSION['bogus']);
```

Another advisable step is to lower the priority of the `add_action()` call:

```
add_action('init', 'register_session', 1);
```

just to make sure you have your session ready before it's needed by another action/function.

Answer (score 2):

Could the same functionality be achieved with [Transients](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API)? i.e.:

```
set_transient( 'username', $_POST['firstname'], MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
```

Sessions are not necessary then.

Answer (score 0):

In your plugins, use wp hook to store session variable.

```
add_action('wp', 'start_my_session');
function start_my_session() {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['myvar'] = 'this is my var';
}
```

Now you can access it from anywhere. for example:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'show_session_var');
function show_session_var() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['myvar'])) echo $_SESSION['myvar'];
}
```