# Sessions in plugin development?

Tags: plugin-development, globals, session

I'm developing a plugin. At present I have two files. **dotmailer.php** and **dotmailer-add.php**. I'm creating a newsletter widget.

My `dotmailer.php` plugin adds an admin menu, with options. It allows the admin to store an email address which is used as authentication for the API I'm using. This is taken from the options page form and stored as such:

```
$apiemail = get_option('apiemail');
```

I've also created a widget, this is the front-facing bit. The user inputs their email in the form and the form POSTs to a new file called **dotmailer-add.php**. So this file has the variable `$useremail` taken from the form.

Now I'm stuck, because I need the var `$useremail` to be useable witin dotmailer-add.php. There is no way to send this through a form or anything because the form already posts through to the wordpress **options.php** file.

I know when working with PHP sessions are often used to store variables that are needed across multiple files. My issue is that the admin will not be submitting the API emal to the Wordpress options page every time they log in, so they won't be starting a new session each time. I need the var `$useremail` to be available across all my plugin files at all times.

I tried using `include` but unfortunately I get whitescreened with no errors (error messages are on).

**How can I set a global variable through Wordpress options and have it available across multiple files within a plugin?**

Comment: If this is only about implementing sessions into WordPress take a look at my [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/117260/22534) about that. If you really want a global variable, likely should not be necessary, you should first take a look at the [PHP Manual - Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Aside from that you probably should add the code that you are working with, because seeing it it's much easier to give an specific answer.

Comment: If WordPress sends through `options.php` file, why don't you retrieve the value via get_option('useremail') Or am I missing something?

Comment: instead of processing the form in `dotmailer-add.php` you could put it in your widget. have the form submit to the current page and include a URL parameter that passes the value of the email address. have the widget code check for the existence of the parameter and perform the processing. this also allows you to replace the widget form with a 'thanks for signing up' message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store and receive variables in WP sessions?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117252/how-to-store-and-receive-variables-in-wp-sessions)