# Which is best to use $_SESSION or WP_Session?

Tags: session

I have little confusion with  $_SESSION   and  WP_Session   over their performance,which one is best to use.
thanks.

Comment: What is WP_Session? Is it a plugin? If so, you could ask to the developer about it.

Comment: best use for what?

Comment: I think performance should be a non issue here, in a sense of same, same, but different - so it shouldn't matter that much. I've given an [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/117260/22534) some time ago, which contains a link that explains some differences between `$_SESSION` and `WP_Session`, maybe that helps you.