# If user has clicked link add class and store using PHP/Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, users, html

I have multiple divs on my website that are clickable. I simply want that when the user clicks this div, a class is then added so they know they have viewed this.

For example, we could have a list of 10 links on the site. Once they click a link, the 'viewed' class would be added, to set a background colour to green.

I know the below is a simply way to do this in jQuery, but if someone could please help with storing this in PHP it would help so much, I am quite stuck on this!

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="clickable-links">
    <div class="link1">Lnk 1</div>
    <div class="link2">Lnk 2</div>
    <div class="link3">Lnk 3</div>
  </div>

  .viewed {
    background: red;
  }

  $(function() {
    $('.clickable-links > div').click(function() {
      $(this).addClass("viewed");
    });
  });
```

Comment: Welcome! You posted this over at Stack Overflow. And I even pointed you to this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117252/how-to-store-and-receive-variables-in-wp-sessions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store and receive variables in WP sessions?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117252/how-to-store-and-receive-variables-in-wp-sessions)

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Im really stuck, I just want to add a class when user has clicked the link but not sure how!

Comment: Adding a class is easy, what you're asking is to store that information - which is what that other answer talks about doing using PHP $_SESSIONS. Have you tried using the default CSS `a:visited` selector? No need for a class.

Comment: Here is the best possible solution to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290959/how-can-i-detect-visited-and-unvisited-links-on-a-page