# $_SESSION dosent't work

Tags: session

So when i use variable `$_SESSION['wp_childs'] = $_POST['childs']` in my plugin,
nothing changes in my storage session.

i use `session_start();` at the top of that all pages; for use `$_SESSION` but i can't store my new session variable.

So i want juste create a new variable session and use it after.

if you have any ideas for store all my variable without global variable i take it.

Thank you !!!

Edit 29/01/2021

it's create_session.php;

```php
<?php

    //Create automatique
    $path = preg_replace('/wp-content(?!.*wp-content).*/','',__DIR__);

    include($path.'wp-load.php');

    function start_my_session() {
        session_start();
    
        $_SESSION['wp_childs'] = $_POST['id'];
        $_SESSION['wp_parents'] = $_POST['id_parent'];
    }

    add_action('wp', 'start_my_session');
 
    // $location = "https://sparklending.fr/5b349-shop/";
    // $status = '303';
    // wp_redirect( $location, $status );
```

Comment: Show you full - or at least more - code - to give context and allow people to help you correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store and receive variables in WP sessions?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117252/how-to-store-and-receive-variables-in-wp-sessions)

Comment: PHP Sessions don't work on a lot of WP hosts, PHP Sessions also have privacy security and scaling problems. Given that a PHP Session requires a cookie to be set to track the session ID, you still need to ask for consent, and you might as well just use cookies. WordPress itself does not use PHP sessions, but uses cookie based sessions instead.

Comment: Also remember that generic PHP problems should go on stackoverflow

Comment: I have already looked at this question but even testing all the possibilities nothing works And with cookies there are deleted when i go to another page in same site.

Comment: @Griffont39 don't post replies as solutions, you'll derail your own question. If cookies are being deleted when you visit another page then you are using cookies incorrectly, that should not happen. If you are doing this because cookies do not work then PHP sessions are not the solution you are hoping for ( as I said, PHP sessions rely on a session ID stored in a cookie, you can't avoid cookies by using PHP sessions )

Comment: Ok so i forget session and i use setcookies for my issues but i create my cookies like this ```setcookie("wp_childs", $_POST['id'],time()+3600);```  with a ```wp_safe_redirect( $location, $status );``` and my cookies is deleted;

Comment: You need to use the edit link under the tags. Only post solutions as solutions to your question. ***Never*** post a comment as an answer. There is an edit link that you can use to modify your question to include more information in the question underneath the tag list.

Comment: Also stop bootstrapping Wordpress via `wp-load.php` then redirecting users, you should never send the user to a standalone PHP file in a WordPress site, it can cause all sorts of problems and issues. Why do you need a session named `wp_childs`? What are you trying to build that lead you to all of this? This is an X Y problem. You've encountered problems, devised solutions, then asked how to fix your solution, not how to solve your problem. Ask about the original thing you were trying to do

Comment: hmm ok i deleted wp-load.php but i aready did my research but i don't find a good answer. So i can't explaine more i need just store few variable somewhere and use it when i need it. i'm so sorry if i don't use this forum neatly and for my english.