# Moving meta boxes in admin

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I have added tags to my custom post type and by default the tag meta box appears under the 'publish' meta box on the right. I can manually drag the meta box to reposition it under the rest of my meta boxes on the left but this is inefficient in deployment.

How can I position the default tags meta box using code like the rest of my meta boxes?

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'admin_boxes' );
function admin_boxes()
{
    add_meta_box( 'display_text_meta_box',
        'Text box',
        'display_text_meta_box',
        'custom_types', 'normal', 'high'
    );
}

function display_text_meta_box( $custom_type ) 
{

}
```

Comment: Are you searching for something like [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161285/how-to-make-open-closed-and-hidden-shown-metaboxes-status-saved-on-a-per-post-ba/166489#166489) or like [this](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/9100450)?

Comment: I used the plugin to disable the meta box order along with @Bainterents answer, but it still displays under the publish meta box...

Comment: Myol, please take some time at the [help] to see how the system works. Bainternet does not get your ping. You will need to comment on his answer ... _sigh_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the default post tags metabox and then add it again in the desired location, ex:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'move_tags_metabox_location', 0 );
function move_tags_metabox_location(){
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    unset( $wp_meta_boxes['post']['side']['core']['tagsdiv-post_tag'] );
    add_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-post_tag', 'Tags', 'post_tags_meta_box', 'post', 'normal', 'core', array( 'taxonomy' => 'post_tag' ));
}
```

Comment: is it critical to use `unset`? I can get this to work with just `add_meta_box`

Comment: it's already added so the unset is crucial.