# Session is not starting

Tags: functions, session

I've read  the usage of `session()` in WordPress from [here](http://silvermapleweb.com/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/) and [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-wordpress-for-web-application-development-features-sessions--wp-34228). And I placed the following code into the very starting of my `functions.php`:

```
/**
*   ENABLING SESSION TO THE SITE
*   Thanks: Shazzad
*   Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16119876/1743124
*/

function register_session() {

    if ( ! session_id() ) {
        session_start();
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_session' );
```

But I can't work with session because that code is failing to start the session. Finally I placed only

```
session_start();
```

at the very beginning of my `functions.php` and it's working fine. I'm using WP 3.9.1.

Is there can be anything wrong, if I proceed with my project running the session start barely at the very beginning?

Comment: Basically: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/105466/21376

Comment: Of note some hosts advise PHP sessions are unreliable, e.g. using PHP sessions on WP Engine can lead to problems ( such as users sharing sessions that shouldn't etc ). Perhaps you'd be better off using cookies and user meta

Comment: What are you trying to do with the session?

Comment: I completed the project that time with the bare session start (`session_start();`) and did the language switching for the site. On @G.M.'s recommendation I checked any `header already sent` check, but found no bug; I always keep my WP_DEBUG true when developing but found no bug either. So it's a kind of problematic project that time. BTW it's working fine now with that bare session start and is functioning as per the client's demand. Thanks all of you.

Answer (score -1):

No, there's no disadvantage to starting a session directly in your theme's `functions.php`.

However, it's strange that starting your session on `init` is not working for you. Could it perhaps be that output is being generated (perhaps a space or a line break) before `init`? Could you turn `WP_DEBUG` on and see if any notices or warnings are being shown?